# Find a linear transformation $ T: \mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{Range}T$ are spanned by given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, dimension-theory-algebra

I have got the following entrance exam question.

> Find a linear transformation $ T: \mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{Range}T$ are respectively spanned by $$\{(1,1,1,1), (1, 0, 0, 1)\} \text{ and } \{(1,1,0), (1, 0, 1)\}$$

---

**My approach**: $\dim \ker T = 2$ and $\dim\operatorname{Range}T = 2$. $T(1,1,1,1) = (0,0,0)$, $T (1, 0, 0, 1)= (0,0,0)$. But with this information I am not able to proceed further. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: complete $\{(1,1,1,1), (1, 0, 0, 1)\}$ into a basis $\{(1,1,1,1), (1, 0, 0, 1), v_3, v_4\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$ and set $T(v_3) = (1, 1, 0)$ and $T(v_4) = (1, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_1=(1,1,1,1)$ and $v_2=(1,0,0,0)$. Now take two other vectors $v_3$ and $v_4$ such that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly independent, such as $v_3=(1,0,0,0)$ and $v_4=(0,1,0,0)$. And then take the only linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T(v_1)=T(v_2)=(0,0,0)$, $T(v_3)=(1,1,0)$, and $T(v_4)=(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response . Next step would be writing arbitrary element of R^4 SAY $(x, y, z, w)$ as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$. Then T(x, y, z, w) will be the ans?

Comment: More precisely, if $(x,y,z,w)=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+\alpha_4v_4$, then $$T(x,y,z,w)=\alpha_3(1,1,0)+\alpha_4(1,0,0)=(\alpha_3+\alpha_4,\alpha_3,0).$$

Comment: Thank you so  much. God bless to the helper